# Unary in $P$, binary not in $P$

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

I would like to know if there is a known decision problem with the following characteristics:

- Represented in unary, the problem is decidable in polynomial time.
- Represented in binary, the problem is not decidable in polynomial time (and this fact has been proved, not just conjectured).

For example, Subset-Sum is in $P$ when represented in unary, but it is $NP$-complete in binary. However, this problem does not satisfy my second requirement because we do not know whether $P=NP$.

Comment: $\{ \langle M, s, x \rangle \mid M \text{ accepts } x \text{ within } s \text{ steps}\}$

Comment: @GMB: Assuming you can show that there is no faster way but simulating $M$ for $s$ steps.

Comment: @Raphael - the language GMB have mentioned is known to be  EXPTIME-complete.

Comment: @RB: Ah, that's important to note then. Too many beginners fall into the trap of thinking along the lines of "I can't find a better algorithm, therefore there is none!".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every single-exponential (i.e. known to be solvable in $O(c^n)$ for some constant $c$) [EXPTIME-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) problem will answer your requirements.

For example, see [checking thorough rerefinement on finite modal transition systems](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~srba/files/BKLS%3aICTAC:09.pdf).

Comment: "solvable in ... for some constant $c$" $\: \mapsto \:$ "in [E](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#e)" $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: One should note that P $\subsetneq$ EXPTIME is known.